# How do I schedule a C# project?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have created one C# project which uses few libraries like [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320445.aspx)

The project has only one class. 
How can I schedule the project to run at a specified time everyday?

Answer (score 2):

Compile your project to an exe and use windows task scheduler to schedule it to run once a day.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  a customized  scheduler  you can try this one 
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/